# Replace a textview by imageview in a listview

Tags: android, listview, textview, imageview

I have a listView showing some text and a recommendation successfully. The recommendation can be "L" or "A". Now i have two images for both each of them. How can i replace the recommendation by that image or just add another image to that list according to the recommendation. Thanx in advance

In other words how can i loop a listview and their values after being made.

This is how i make my listview.

```
this.setListAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(Grammar_tab_all.this, testdata ,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "name","recom"},
    new int[] { R.id.module_name_item, R.id.module_recom,}));
        final ListView lv = getListView();
```

now how to loop that listview so that i can compare the recommendation values?

Comment: I don't understand. 
But how about checking recommendation with `if...else` and set accordingly ?
Can u explain a little more detail ?

Answer (score 0):

Well then, what u need is custom listview. Hope [this link](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429) can help you with u'r problem.